# Using DN in Search Filter

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

In my LDAP Client program sometimes I have to include the DN value within the search filter. But this DN is changing frequently and every I have to change this filter in my code.

When I googled it for that I got something like this

Suppose you want to pull all users of ObjectType = Person from the R&D and HR ous, but not any users from Marketing and PM. The filter would be:

```
(&(objectClass=person)(|(ou:dn:=ResearchAndDevelopment)(ou:dn:=HumanResources)))
```

Can anybody explain this more in detail?

Answer (score 19):

You should check [RFC 2254](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2254) (The String Representation of LDAP Search Filters).

LDAP filters use [polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) for the boolean operators. So the operator is written before its operands:

```
(&(condition1)(condition2)(condition3)...)
```

The example above means that you want all LDAP entries which satisfy *condition1 **AND** condition2 **AND** condition3* and so on.

Then there are condition themselves. They are very simple and can consist only of few types:

- present condition - `(attrName=*)`
- simple condition - `(attrName>=value)` / `(attrName<=value)` / `(attrNamevalue=value)` / `(attrName~=value)`
- substring condition - `(attrName=*value*)` / `(attrName=*value)` / `(attrName=value*)`
- extensible condition - `(attrName:dn:=value)` / `(attrName:matchingRule:=value)`

The *extensible condition* with the `:dn:` keyword means, that you want attributes from the entry DN to be considered as well. So for your case entry `cn=John Doe,ou=HumanResources,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com` would match the filter `(ou:dn:=HumanResource)`.

---

Translating your example filter to an English sentence would be:

> Find me all LDAP entries which have `objectClass` equal to `person` and have either `ResearchAndDevelopment` or `HumanResources` in their `ou` attribute or somewhere on their DN.

Comment: Note that support for these conditions varies by vendor. For example, Active Directory does not support extensible conditions and treats approximate equal (`~=`) and equal (`=`) identically. [Reference.](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dn into base and set search scope as `base`.

That is, set **dn value** into **base**, and set **search scope** as `base`(search scope is one of base, sub and one).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to search by the whole DN, you can search with:

```
(distinguishedName=CN=MyCommonName,OU=SomeEnv,...,DC=SomeDir)
```