# Retrieving multiple objects from LDAP by DN at once

Tags: language-agnostic, ldap

I have a list of DNs, and for performance reasons I want to retrieve the attributes of every DN in the list in a single trip to the LDAP server.

Seems like searching by DN, i.e., using DN as a filter search, is not possible

[Using DN in Search Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472994/using-dn-in-search-filter)

http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200503/msg00520.html

....is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is only possible in Active Directory. All I had to do is filter by the `distinguishedName` attribute, however on my tests there was no performance gain.

> Active Directory includes the distinguishedName attribute on every
>   object; the value is the object's DN. The following example elaborates
>   the previous example to include a value of distinguishedName on each
>   object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223167.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can.

```
ldapsearch -h <ldaphost>  -b "cn=joe,dc=yourdoamin,dc=com" -s base -D cn=admin,dc=yourdomain,dc=com -W "(objectclass=*)" "*"
```

Will retrieve all user attributes for the DN: cn=joe,dc=yourdoamin,dc=com.

But, for the list, you would need to repeat the search for each one.
We often do this in a bash script.

Can you use a filter to identify which DNs you need?

-jim

Comment: Thanks for your answer jim. Perhaps the question is not clear, what I am trying to avoid is the _need to repeat the search for each one_.

Comment: AFIK, you have no choice. This should not be a significant issue for the LDAP server as each search by DN should be only a few milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks again @jwilleke. Sure it won't be a problem for the LDAP server but there would be a network overhead. This becomes an issue with tens of thousands of DNs